# RxJS 3 conditional filter

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have 3 conditional numeric dropdown with a values `-1`; `0`; `1`; and `Observable<Thing[]>` datasource that I need to filter on based on dropdown.  I need to display or hide a particular rows based on dropdown:

- 1. keep all the items (no filter) (`-1`)
- 2. filter only that have no specific field (or field is empty)  (`0`)
- 3. filter only that have specific field (`1`)

I am trying to figure out how to connect the filter and my dropdown so based on a particular value I have related items to display.

```
dataSource$ = originalDataSource$.filter((item:any) => { 
 // check the conditions here
});
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You really have an observable of `Thing`, not `Thing[]`, are you sure? So you're not filtering an array of data but a stream of data over time?

Comment: @IngoBürk you are right, that was a typo. Edited. I want to filter the array of data

Comment: Then you need the map operator on observable level and inside that use the array filter method. You have to be careful about the difference of rxjs and array operators.

Comment: The filter value is an Observable as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create observable with currently selected value, can be something like:

```
var dropDownElement = document.getElementById('dropDown');
var dropDownValue$ = Observable
  .fromEvent(dropDownElement, 'change')
  .map(e => e.target.value)
  .startWith(dropDownElement.value);
```

then to map filter predicate and to combine it with original datasource:

```
var filterPredicate$ = dropDownValue$.map(dropDownValue => {
  if (dropDownValue == 0) return element => {…};
  if (dropDownValue == 1) return element => {…};
  return () => true;
});

var dataSource$ = Observable.combineLatest(
  filterPredicate$, originalDataSource$, 
  (predicate, data) => data.filter(predicate)
);
```

Comment: what you put in to `{…};` ?

Comment: element to be Thing from filtered list, so it is to be something like: `return !element.specificField` (for check if field is not present)

Comment: Tried `return (element: any) => { element.specificField === '' };` saying `[tslint] unused expression, expected an assignment or function call (no-unused-expression)`

Comment: try `return (element: any) => element.specificField === ''` ;)